# get id from a nested div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent

I don't know how to put this. This has got a bit messy. I couldn't use the right words to ask the question. Here is my code:

```html
<div id="addfieldcontainerdropdown">
    <div id="addDropdownfield">
        <div id="div0">
            <select name="0" style="margin: 20px" id="0">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <input style="margin: 7px" id="1" placeholder="Value" onkeyup="check_if_value_set(this); return false;"
                   type="text">

            <span style="margin: 7px;cursor: pointer;" onclick="remove_fields(this);return false;"><iclass="fa fa-times"></i></span>
        </div>

        <div id="div2">
            <select name="2" style="margin: 20px" id="2">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <input style="margin: 7px" id="3" placeholder="Value" onkeyup="check_if_value_set(this); return false;"
                   type="text">

            <span style="margin: 7px;cursor: pointer;" onclick="remove_fields(this);return false;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
        </div>

        <div id="div4">
            <select name="4" style="margin: 20px" id="4">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <input style="margin: 7px" id="5" placeholder="Value" onkeyup="check_if_value_set(this); return false;"
                   type="text">
            <span style="margin: 7px;cursor: pointer;" onclick="remove_fields(this);return false;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_new_text_field(this);event.preventDefault();return false;" style="cursor:pointer">

    <span id="add_new_span" class="addnew" style="float: none;margin-left: 1%;"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i>Add New Field</span>

    </a>
</div>
```

You can see there is a function named "show_new_text_field(this)" at the bottom of the code. Using this function, i need to get the id of say, div4 or select box of id 4. How can this be done ? I tried using prent() and closest(). Nothing worked. Any type of suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: If you're doing it by `id` you don't need relative references, you can specifically select it by doing `$('#div4')...` - However, your question hasn't clearly defined what you're trying to select and under which circumstances. Please elaborate.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just target the div directly with `$('#div4')?`

Comment: You probably want `$(that).closest('[id]').attr('id')`

Comment: Those ids are generating dynamically... and i need the name of the last id created...

Comment: And also the first select box within that last div...

Comment: @PlabonDutta Check out my answer and see if it helps. I'm still a bit unclear on exactly what you need, between names, ID's, etc, however you should be able to work with the answer I've provided to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Santi actually its complicated.. i've created the name of those ids dynamically with numbers... when the function is called, based on certain criteria, the first select box, of the last id becomes an input box....also there are some other stuffs... your ans looks fine...i think it will work...except i dont know how would i want to select only the last id if it hadn't had a name starting with "div"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var lastDiv = $("[id^=div]").last(); //Get Last div whose ID begins with "div"
var lastDivId = lastDiv.attr('id'); //Get ID of that div
var firstSelect = lastDiv.find('select').first(); //Get the first 'select' of that div
var firstSelectId = firstSelect.attr('id'); //Get that select's ID

console.log("Last Div: " + lastDivId); // "Last Div: div4"
console.log("First Select in " + lastDivId + ": " + firstSelectId); //"First Select in div4: 4"
```

In the event your div won't always start with "div", you could just select the last child `div` of your parent (`addDropdownfield`) by doing this:

```
var lastDiv = $("#addDropdownfield div").last(); //Get all children divs of addDropdownfield - from that list, just the last one
```

Comment: @Santi- looks great...i'll put it in my code...however, what if my id hadn't started with "div" ? How would it be selected then ? I mean how could i select the last div id belonging any name ?

Comment: If the div you are looking for will always be a child of `addDropdownfield`, you could do `$("#addDropdownfield div").last();` - `$("#addDropdownfield div")` selects all divs that are a child of `addDropdownfield`, and then `.last();` grabs the last one. I've adjusted my answer above.

Comment: @Santi- sorry to bother you again...what if I run through a loop and need to select only a particular div from them say, number 3 ?
var divs = $("#addDropdownfield div")[2]; can something like this be done ?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. If you had a variable that stored this changing number, and your div's id *contained* that number, you could also do something like `$("#div"+i);` - If `i` was 3, it would select id `div3`, etc.